# After training a custom object detection model using Roboflow, all of the predicted objected are switched

Tags: computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, yolov5, roboflow

I have been using roboflow to annotate door and door handle images, (about 1300 images).

For generating the model, I have used auto-orientation and resizing to 416*416 to pre-process
and vertical flip for augmentation.
After testing the model on a webcam and seeing the test set predictions, the model seemed to predict doors as door handles and door handles as doors almost in every image.

**In a nutshell, the issue is that the model predicts the bonding boxes accurately however have all the labels switched.**

I have also tried using the yolov5 github code and it has the same issue.

I can not pin point where is the problem. I would appreciate any help in this matter and any tips to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Sounds likely there's a problem with the dataset. Is this shared publicly? Can you post a link?

Comment: @BradDwyer Suspected that but I found it rather strange as I double checked the annotations and they seem fine. Here's the link: universe.roboflow.com/uaeu/door-and-handles-detection

Comment: This looks like it might be a bug in the dataloader. I'm wondering if it's getting confused because one class is a substring of the other. Could you try generating a version where you add the remap preprocessing step to change "door handle" to "handle" and see if that works any better? (PS - I added some additional training credits to your account for you.)

Comment: @BradDwyer The problem was indeed because of the naming, it works fine after the remap, thank you so much.